# Python Permission Error when reading

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, permissions, file-permissions

```
import os
import rarfile

file = input("Password List Directory: ")
rarFile = input("Rar File: ")

passwordList = open(os.path.dirname(file+'.txt'),"r")
```

with this code I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nick     L\Desktop\Programming\PythonProgramming\RarCracker.py", line 7, in <module>
    passwordList = open(os.path.dirname(file+'.txt'),"r")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Nick L\\Desktop'
```

This is weird because I have full permission to this file as I can edit it and do whatever I want, and I am only trying to read it. Every other question I read on stackoverflow was regarding writing to a file and getting a permissions error.

Comment: Right, It give me ''Permission denied" error when i try to open a directory

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to open a *directory*, not a file, because of the call to `dirname` on this line:

```python3
passwordList = open(os.path.dirname(file+'.txt'),"r")
```

To open the file instead of the directory containing it, you want something like:

```python3
passwordList = open(file + '.txt', 'r')
```

Or better yet, use the `with` construct to guarantee that the file is closed after you're done with it.

```python3
with open(file + '.txt', 'r') as passwordList:
    # Use passwordList here.
    ...

# passwordList has now been closed for you.
```

On Linux, trying to open a directory raises an `IsADirectoryError` in Python 3.5, and an `IOError` in Python 3.1:

> IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/kjc/'

I don't have a Windows box to test this on, but according to [Daoctor's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711568/python-permission-error-when-reading#comment64800837_38711568), at least one version of Windows raises a `PermissionError` when you try to open a directory.

PS:  I think you should either trust the user to enter the whole directory-and-file name him- or herself --- without you appending the `'.txt'` to it --- or you should ask for just the directory, and then append a default filename to it (like `os.path.join(directory, 'passwords.txt')`).

Either way, asking for a "directory" and then storing it in a variable named `file` is guaranteed to be confusing, so pick one or the other.

Comment: The Windows API error is `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` when you try to open a directory as a regular file (as opposed to as a directory). It's not a particularly helpful error, especially considering that the source error coming from the NT kernel is the much more helpful `STATUS_FILE_IS_A_DIRECTORY`. Unfortunately the Windows API is from ancient times and probably trying to remain compatible with Win16 running on MS-DOS.

Comment: @eryksun  Thanks for the background...  I was wondering why the error message was so misleading.

Answer (score 2):

os.path.dirname() will return the Directory in which the file is present not the file path. For example if file.txt is in path= 'C:/Users/Desktop/file.txt' then os.path.dirname(path)wil return 'C:/Users/Desktop' as output, while the open() function expects a file path.
You can change the current working directory to file location and open the file directly.

```
os.chdir(<File Directory>)
open(<filename>,'r')
```

or

```
open(os.path.join(<fileDirectory>,<fileName>),'r')
```